# Why can't I do a "with x as (...)" with ADODB and Oracle?

Tags: vba, oracle, common-table-expression, adodb, recordset

I fail to execute an SQL query with a *with clause* via ADODB and Oracle.

That is, the following snippet works:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.connection
Set cn = ....

Dim rs As ADODB.recordSet
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "select 'foo' x from dual", cn


Do While Not rs.eof
   ...
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

However, the following doesn't work - it genererats a **Run-Time error 3704: Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.**

```
Dim cn As ADODB.connection
Set cn = ....

Dim rs As ADODB.recordSet
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "with w as (select 'foo' x from dual) select x from w", cn

Do While Not rs.eof
   ...
   rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Obviously, this is a trimmed-down demonstration of the real problem which consists
of a more sophisticated query.

It seems to me that ADODB sort of parses the query before it passes it to the Oracle instance and does not understand the *with clause*. Anyway, any help on this is highly
appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, it really seems as though ADODB expects a query statement to actually start with `select`.
Therefore, a work around for the problem might be to enclose the statement in a `select * from ( .... )` like so:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "with w as (select 'foo' x from dual) select x from w"

' enclose the statement:
sql = "select * from (" & sql & ")"

rs.Open sql, cn
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh man that's gonna save me a lot of work! I write a lot of Oracle queries in ADODB and have been avoiding using the WITH satement. This will provide much more clarity. I would up vote this a hundred times if I could.

Comment: I don't know what to say. This is soooo stupid on MS's part. a serious WTF.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it really helped me.

Comment: That saved me some time!  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: OMG Thanks! It has been 5 days that I am looking for a solution to this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Above method did not work for me.

Adding ";" prior to WITH keyword resolved the issue.

Dim sql As String
sql = ";with w as (select 'foo' x from dual) select x from w"

rs.Open sql, cn

Comment: Works as advertised.