# ADODB Recordset: Operation not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, adodb

This a sample query producing the same error but I have much complex query.

```
sqlText = "with t as (select * from dual) select * from t"

Cmd.CommandText = sqlText
Set rs = Cmd.Execute

Do While Not rs.EOF
    For col = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Str = Str & " - " & rs.Fields(col).Value
    Next col
    rs.MoveNext
    Str = Str & vbNewLine
Loop
```

I don't get any error if I use the query without "with", example as

```
sqlText = "select * from dual"
```

That's why I wonder what difference it makes in excel VBA with the above two sql queries and like to know if there is workaround. I still can write the sql query differently to produce the same output without using "with" but that won't just make my doubt go away, so like to hear an explanation from experts.

Comment: It will make a difference what database you're using so it would be useful to say...  Looks like Oracle?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316886/why-cant-i-do-a-with-x-as-with-adodb-and-oracle

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams, I couldn't find that question you provided before I post this. I can't believe there is so simple workaround :)

Comment: SET NOCOUNT ON; - in first line helps for me

Answer (score 0):

Before the select statement, attach a declaration like this:

```
    Dim sqlText As String
    sqlText = "with t as (select * from dual) select * from t"
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
Cmd.CommandText = sqlText
Set rs.Source = cmd
rs.Open

Do Until rs.EOF
```

`Cmd.Execute` is used for commands, e.g. `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. For queries you have to use `Open`

Which provide do you use? Most likely the *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle* (`MSDAORA`). This provider is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) for I think 20 years and should not be used. Certainly it does not support subquery factoring, i.e. `WITH`-Clause.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue, this one did [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316886/why-cant-i-do-a-with-x-as-with-adodb-and-oracle)